# Converting a Compressed Image to QImage

Tags: ros, python, pyqt, compressedimage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I need to create a camera feed viewer that will need to run on very limited bandwidth networks. As such I want to use Compressed images instead of the raw image.

My application is python and uses PyQt for the gui.

How can I convert the /sensor_msgs/Compressed message to a QtGui.Qimage ?

Thanks

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205870/converting-a-compressed-image-to-qimage/) by [David L-B](https://answers.ros.org/users/21974/david-l-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it myself:

```
qimage = QtGui.QImage.fromData(compressedImage.data)
imageMain = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
self.ui.label1.setPixmap(imageMain)
```

---

Originally posted by [David L-B](https://answers.ros.org/users/21974/david-l-b/) with karma: 71 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-09-14**:
`from PyQt4 import QtGui`

**Comment by [beingtrippy](https://answers.ros.org/users/50798/beingtrippy/) on 2020-08-15**:
Can you elaborate how to give input to compressedIamge.data using publisher/subscriber ?

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2020-08-17**:
Have a look at ImageTransport::Publisher: http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages .